# Poner dos div con img en la misma línea y poner texto encima

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando hacer una especie de botones con una imagen que al pulsar me redireccionen a otro sitio, y quiero que estas estén en el centro y el texto también este en el centro y encima de estas fotos, pero no logro encontrar la forma más 'correcta' de hacerlo.

Este es mi código html

```
<div class="cabecera_colabora">Colabora</div>
                 
                 <div class="cont_colabora">
                     
                     <a href="voluntariado.php>"><img src=assets/img/foto2.jpg> Voluntario</a>
                     <a href="otrasformas.php>"><img src=assets/img/foto1.jpg> otras formas</a>
```

Esto es lo que quiero hacer más o menos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Una forma seria asi:

HTML: pones un div (puede ser otra etiqueta tambien) al que vas a aplicarle la imagen de fondo y dentro el enlace que va a ser el boton que te redirija a donde quieres

```css
.boton{
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 160px;
   height: 120px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: inline-flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
  }
  .boton a{
   background-color: #ffffff70;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .img1{
   background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/160/120/animals");
  }
  .img2{
   background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/160/120/people");
  }
```

```html
<div class="boton img1"><a href="otrasformas.php>">otras formas</a></div>
 <div class="boton img2"><a href="algoMas.php>">Algo mas</a></div>
```

CSS: Luego con css le das al div la imagen que quieras de fondo, le das que no se repita y le indicas las medidas que quieres para la imagen. Luego haces a ese div un container flex para poder centrar al enlace. Despues puedes estilizar el enlace a gusto

**EDITADO**

Ahi te hice una modificacion para que con minimos cambios en css y html puedas tener varios botones con distinta imagen y distinto texto. Esto se logra usando clases, la clase boton esta en ambos div con lo cual toman los mismos estilos y la clase img1 e img2 solo estan para cambiar las imagenes de fondo

Comment: pero para crear dos botones con imagenes diferentes cada uno debe tener su propio div no?